# Jquery plugin for user mappings?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am building a web application using asp.net, which has three types of user's admin, dealers, and employees (under dealers). The employees can be associated with more than one dealers and which can be done only by the "admin".

So what i need is to make a neat employee and dealers mapping page visible to the admin.
but am not getting any ideas, in order how to achieve that. The mappings can be in a graphical format (using any jquery plugin) or can be in  a simple interactive tabular format.

Searched for jquery plugin, but had no luck.

Please help me out, need suggestions or demo page views of similar structure or any jquery plugins to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Drag & Drop plugin of jQuery? It's simple and will provide a nice and easy way for the admin to associate employees with dealers by simply dragging and dropping them. Some nice example of this plugin is given here: [jQuery UI - Draggable Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default)